# Explain Bonpensiero's appearance in this scene?

Tags: the-sopranos

So I was watching The Sopranos S03E02. As you all know, "Big Pussy" Bonpensiero was killed somewhere in the end of season 2, but in season 3, I saw a really strange thing...

[image]

After Tony's mom's funeral, Tony, Christopher and Furio were talking at Tony's house and then we see Big Pussy in the mirror. He's dead and now I can see him in the mirror. Could anyone explain me what this means?

Comment: In that photo he looks menacing. If I recall correctly, he was still in the show a bit longer, flash backs and what not.

Comment: Pussy was a ghost in that scene

Answer (score 9):

Big Pussy was killed by Tony, Pauli and Silvio for being an FBI informer - however he had been a very close friend to all of them, and it is hinted in the series that they are all bothered by their involvement in their killing of a friend.

Pussy's appearance in the mirror is after Tony's mother's funeral, when clearly he would be thinking about the past and about death.  Throughout The Sopranos the importance of dreams and daydreams is explored - indeed Tony's final acceptance that Pussy might be an informer comes after a dream that he has where he has a conversation with Pussy as a fish.

[Clip from YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo6cNQwN6LQ)

It is my interpretation of this appearance of Pussy, is that he is thinking / daydreaming about his old friend.